# Getting staking rewards by stake public key

Tags: staking, rewards

How to get rewards for staking account?
I try to use getInflationReward but I receive exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the right approach, you may be using the call incorrectly. Try doing:

```
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getInflationReward",
    "params": [
       ["<STAKE_PUBKEY_AS_BASE_58>"]
    ]
  }
'
```

More information at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getinflationreward

Comment: seems like it's quite slow takes up to 10 seconds and sometimes 30 seconds for me. is there any way to speed up this call?

Answer (score 0):

I put together this script to figure staking rewards from the activation epoch to current for a given stake account...It uses Solana CLI instead of an api call though...

https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6406/722